# Conver RDD to Dataset/DataFrame in Mobius

Tags: apache-spark, mobius

Is there an easy way to convert an RDD to a Dataset (or DataFrame) in Mobius. Basically something similar to the functionality provided by scala's

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
```

I know there's sqlContext.CreateDataFrame() but as far as I can tell that requires me to define my own StructType in order to do the conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For now, [sqlContext.CreateDataFrame](https://github.com/Microsoft/Mobius/blob/master/csharp/Adapter/Microsoft.Spark.CSharp/Sql/SqlContext.cs#L139) is the only option. Feel free to create an issue in Mobius repo to get the discussion started if you think ToDF() is required on RDDs.